# How can I restore login functionality at Firebase after integrating with Google?

Tags: android, firebase, google-api-client, firebase-authentication

I am developing an Android App using Firebase. I had everything running fine up to this morning. I went to Firebase, imported the project at their new console and then I tried to add Analytics to my app.

At this point I couldn't use Google login, and I guess it was because adding Analytics I skipped to add my SHA-1 key, so the newest information at Google was that I didn't have a SHA-1 key. I didn't see that I had to whitelist my Google app which was actually login in people in my app, and that was a big mistake. Trying to solve it I begun to change things, so many that I couldn't even list them here. A short version could be:

- I updated the Android SKD Manager.
- I changed the dependencies for Gradle. Still not working.
- I saw that I could give my SHA-1 key to Firebase, but I had a alert saying that this key was already in use by another App (the one at Google API)
- In order to solve it, I deleted the credentials of my Google API App -*not so good idea*-
- Then I used my SHA-1 key at Firebase. Still not working.
- I tried to put everything as it was at the beginning, but now I cannot delete my key from Firebase. What I've done is write a random key to be able to use it at Google API.
- I went to Google API and created a new credential for the App that I was using and was working fine up to this morning.
- I whitelisted the App ID at my Firebase Auth settings. Still not working

Surely I have done other stuff but I don't even remember.

Now I have the following error when I try to login with Google, **but also with Facebook**(?!), and I haven't tried with other providers. The error says:

```
FirebaseLoginError = PROVIDER_NOT_ENABLED: Make sure google login is enabled and configured in your Firebase. (FirebaseError: Invalid authentication credentials provided.)
```

There are so many things that could lead to a problem that I have been trying to fix it during all the morning and I am still **completely lost**.

**What should I do to restore everything as it was?**

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on iOS, I believe I have followed the migration instructions in detail, double checked and triple checked everything but at FB sign-in after a successful Google sign-in I get a FIRAuthErrorDomain code 17999 error that is Internal Error.

Comment: Please reach out to us at -> https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

And indicate your project ids (both for the Firebase project and the Google API app)